# Oracle on insert trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm writing a trigger to update a table whenever I add a record to a different table. Basically, I have a table for user records. Whenever I add a record to that table, I want a trigger to create some permissions for that new user. There is a table that has all the user roles and associated permissions stored in it. The way to create new permissions is with a full outer join between the users table and the role_permissions table. That SQL looks like this

```
insert into user_perms (user_id, perm_id, value)
select personnel.user_id AS user_id, role_perms.perm_id AS perm_id, role_perms.value AS value
from personnel
full outer join role_perms on role_perms.personnel_role_id = personnel.personnel_role_id
where personnel.user_id = NEW USER ID;
```

I'm trying to replicate this behavior using a trigger. I can't seem to get it to work. Here's the trigger I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_perms_on_create_user
BEFORE INSERT
   ON users
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   v_user_id number(25);

BEGIN

   -- Find user_id of the record being inserted into the table
   SELECT :NEW.user_id INTO v_user_id
   FROM users;

   -- Insert records into user_perms table
   insert into user_perms 
   (user_id, 
    perm_id, 
    value)
   select personnel.user_id AS user_id, 
          role_perms.perm_id AS perm_id, 
          role_perms.value AS value
   from personnel
   full outer join role_perms 
     on role_perms.personnel_role_id = personnel.personnel_role_id
   where user_id = v_user_id;

END;

/
```

Right now I'm getting this error.

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

I thought it might work as an after insert at first, but that didn't work so I tried it before. I'm not sure now what thing to try next. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to put `:NEW.user_id INTO v_user_id` for each user. That is why multiple result error. Instead just use the value in your query.

```
insert into user_perms 
   (user_id, perm_id, value)
   select :NEW.user_id AS user_id, 
          role_perms.perm_id AS perm_id, 
          role_perms.value AS value
   from personnel
   full outer join role_perms 
     on role_perms.personnel_role_id = personnel.personnel_role_id
   where user_id = :NEW.user_id ;
```

NOTE: Just be carefull the order you put the trigger, because this is BEFORE UDPATE. so maybe the data isnt there yet.

Comment: Ok, I did some refactoring and now I get this error.
`table OK_LIBRARIES_DEV.PERSONNEL is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`

I changed the trigger to run on the personnel table because I was calling data from it, but it doesn't update until after the users table. Additionally, I changed the trigger to an after trigger and followed your suggestions. I'll debug myself unless you spot an obvious error. Thanks a ton for your help.